# Crear Modal para búsqueda de Items - ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo una consulta, me gustaría crear un modal que me permita buscar una lista de items para poder seleccionar pero quisiera una idea de como se puede construir para que mi ventana modal al escribir pueda ubicar y seleccionar lo buscado por su descripción.

Código de ventana para búsqueda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="formulario-datos-both">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Co_auxi, "Codigo Auxiliar", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Co_auxi, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2", @Value = Model.Co_auxi })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.De_ti_auxi_empr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control2", @Value = Model.De_co_auxi_empr, @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = true, style = "width: padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;" })
            <button id="myBtn" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container mt-3">

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Búsqueda de Elementos</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Seleccionar</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar AJAX:

```
$(function() {

    $("myBtn").click(function(e) {
            var descripcion = $("#idDescripcion").val();

            // Aquí modificas dependiendo de tus controladores y acciones
            $.get("/Home/Index?filtro="+descripcion,function(r){
               // Cuando finalice la llamada puedes realizar algo en el cliente
            });

    });

});
```

Tu acción en el controlador debería de ser algo parecido a esta:

```
public ActionResult Index(string filtro)
{
    var lista;

    // Realizas proceso de búsqueda con el filtro y validaciones

    // var lista = datos.Select(r=>r).Where(r=> r.descripcion.Contains(filtro));

    return View(lista);
}
```

He visto que recomiendan utilizar una vista parcial, ya que solo actualizarás una parte de tu vista. Sin embargo no las he utilizado mucho, solo sé que podrías revisar si la solicitud viene de Ajax y con ello determinar qué vista regresarás:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView(lista);

return View(lista);
```

Espero que te ayude, saludos.